# .exe file not recognized after resigning the manifest on ClickOnce Publish

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015, clickonce

I am using MVS 2015 with .Net Framework 4.5.
I publish my C# WF Application, everything is fine, but I have to obfuscate the .exe from Application Files.
After I do it, obviously, the setup does not recognize anymore the .exe, the hashes are different and so on.

I resign the new .exe added file with Signtool providing the necessary .pfx and password, then I use Mage to update the .manifest and the .application [according to the second part of this MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465299.aspx).

Everything is successful, but when I run the setup and I hit install, after a while (around 80% of the installation progress) I receive an error that says that there is something wrong with the new .exe file:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.16299.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.7.2556.0 built by: NET471REL1
    clr.dll             : 4.7.2633.0 built by: NET471REL1LAST_C
    dfdll.dll           : 4.7.2556.0 built by: NET471REL1
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.16299.15 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///E:/share/myApp.application
    Application url         : file:///E:/share/myApp.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : myApp.exe.application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6500754c4a44ec95, processorArchitecture=msil
    Application Identity        : myApp.exe, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6500754c4a44ec95, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of E:\share\myApp.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file myApp.exe: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. 
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [24.03.2018 11:03:32] : Activation of E:\share\myApp.application has started.
    * [24.03.2018 11:03:32] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [24.03.2018 11:03:32] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [24.03.2018 11:03:33] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [24.03.2018 11:03:35] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [24.03.2018 11:03:35] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [24.03.2018 11:03:43] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file myApp.exe: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. 
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.OnModified()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have investigated Marko application, and if you have in use .NET Refactor and have a problem from above here is workaround for get it working:

- .Net Reactor has a Visual Studio Add-In that [needs installed and configured](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2693d842-9730-40f6-858b-8344a0022457/how-to-use-net-reactor-to-protect-vsto-clickonce-solution?forum=vsto) in the project
- Anti ILDASM from .Net Reactor (option that's enabled by default) [has to be disabled when obfuscating](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/388156-click-once-deployment-error-with-net-reactor/) so that MVS could do the proper packing process

Anyway, if you gonna modify your assemblies after publish you need to recompute hash anyway. How it's possible:

1. Don't use a Visual Studio publish engine and generate you
   application    by "mage.exe". It's let to you prepare you source
   application first    and create ClickOnce application after.
2. Download utility from second download link [[here]](http://www.devowl.net/2017/04/Alternative-Mage-UI-Sozdanie-ClickOnce-prilozheniya.html). Execute and [Choose] your folder > Change action to [Update] > and [Build]. No more actions required. Update operation will recompute hashs.
3. If your obfuscator software supports command line parameters then you can add "Post-build event" script in your .exe VS project properties and it will be executed before clickonce build.

"Deploying Obfuscated Assemblies" article you can found here: [Securing ClickOnce Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76e4d2xw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I will check your tutorial out as soon as I can and return with an outcome. Thank you for your time, Sergey!

Comment: I don't think I understood what you said. I will say to you a little more clear: I publish the project (setup.exe, .application file and Application Files folder are present), I change myApp.exe file with my new one. I am using your tool with UPDATE option but it says "SourcePath application file name is not equals to DeploymentUrl file name." when I hit build. But then again, I am not sure that I need UPDATE, I tried the RESIGN option, but when I run the setup it says that the manifest is corrupt.

Comment: After I resign the app with your tool, te error I receive when I install it is the same as presented in the main thread. :(

Comment: You need exactly update option first and resign then. Could you please post here raw error text file content? Btw, don't forget replace .application file near setup.exe on file from UPDATED "Application Files" folder.

Comment: I copy the new .exe, I use Update option (no errors, no warnings), I resign (no errors, no warnings), I replace .application and after that I get the error ("Unable to retrieve application files. Files corrupt in deployement.") at around 80% of the installation. I've updated the full error in the initial post.

Comment: Could you please open your .exe in any text editor and check for <assembly /> manifest inside like [here](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-2aY-F70K6dg/WQDcNU2mH8I/AAAAAAAAArs/MWUDfxJ23WEtywYH8KWN2bDWfQNFZRfnwCLcB/s640/Pic1.png). If your obfuscator have added assembly identity then you need to remove it first.

Comment: My .exe does not have that beautiful <node> structure, it's only "System.Resources Type get_Assembly Assembly t7wWADH8g CultureInfo System.Globalization juRekXgtq   V1yTeaCotrWKGpOafq L4ZJA34VdnK3IH9AxX nKtNZZT9RgPWCQQS6k HJjCIPgcoOD2OAMsxr ekHxw0fw1t1kXo8nhX RuntimeTypeHandle token bciNvGsjYgS98Ibv8i GetTypeFromHandle EESQLO9RAi9RlTNXc8 z7ttc8Inj sX5ATgfla" kind of stuff.
Anyway, I really appreciate your help, Sergey, thank you for your time! I will find a different way to do it, maybe copy the obfuscated .exe later.

Comment: Sure. Anyway you can try out next 2 of 3 suggestions.

Comment: .NetReactor supports command lines and I managed to create a .bat file that generates the obfuscated .exe with .NetReactor. Next, I copy the generated .exe in /bin/Release and in obj/Release, obj/Debug, but when I Publish it is still the old .exe present in the deployed setup. :( And in my application project the .exe is the correct copied obfuscated one. From where does the Publisher takes it's .exe? Can you please tell me where should I copy the obfuscated .exe?

Comment: Put your bat script in "Post-build event" (suggestion number 3) [Exe project property](http://www.aaronstannard.com/images/2015/vs-build-tasks/blank-build-event.png). (I have done a mistake, "before build" is wrong event for you)

Comment: Yes, I know, I've realized that. I put my script in post-build event, the obfuscated .exe is at the end of the build were it should be in /bin and in /obj, but the generated Publish setup STILL contains the old .exe (not obfuscated one). That's why I was asking  where does the Publisher takes it's files from?

Comment: I don't have 100 insure, but you can try 2 steps. 
1. In "Build events" tabe choose "Run the post-build event" on "Always"
2. Try to obfuscate assembly from obj/(Debug/Release) folder.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I did it, the publisher takes the obfuscated .exe, finally, BUT, when I run the setup from that publisher deployment it says the initial error from the post. :)) I can't believe this! It's exhausting, but again, I appreciate your involvement, Sergey! If I ever  manage to do this, I will return with an answer! :D

Comment: No problems :) I think you have some untypical behavior and if your application is not private could you please give me your ClickOnce folder for tests or if it's published somewhere then let me know on xyliman[A]gmail. It's very interesting for me. Thanks